# dynamic button in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

in my jsp i have a table constructed dynamically like the following:

'   retour.append("");

```
            try {
```

s= HibernateUtil.currentSession();
tx=s.beginTransaction();
Query query = s.createQuery(HQL_QUERY);

```
 for(Iterator it=query.iterate();it.hasNext();)
 {                                                                           
                   if(it.hasNext()){

                       Dailytimesheet object=(Dailytimesheet)it.next();                        
                       retour.append("<td>" +object.getActivity() +"</td>");
                       retour.append("<td>" +object.getProjectCode() + "</td>");
                       retour.append("<td>"  +object.getWAName() +  "</td>");
                       retour.append("<td>"  +object.getTaskCode() +"</td>");
                       retour.append("<td>"  +object.getTimeFrom() +"</td>");
                       retour.append("<td>" +object.getTimeSpent() + "</td>");
                       retour.append("<td>" +object.getPercentTaskComplete() + "</td>");
                       if (droitdaccess)
                       {
```

retour.append("");
retour.append("");
retour.append("");

```
                       retour.append("<td  bordercolor=#FFFFFF>");
                       retour.append("<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"id_"+nomTab+"_"+compteur+"\"  value=\""+object.getIdDailyTimeSheet()+"\"/>");
                       retour.append("<img src=\"icon_delete.gif\" onClick=\"deletearowById('id_"+nomTab+"_"+compteur+"')\" style=\"cursor:pointer\"  name=\"action\"  value=\"deleting\" />");
                       retour.append("</td>");

                       }
                       }

                       compteur++;    
                       retour.append("</tr>");


 }   

retour.append ("</table>");'
```

next to the table i want to display a button named send in order to send the table content.
I  do not really want to dispaly this button where the table is empty.

So at least if the table is populated by only one record i want that button being displayed.
How should i deal in this case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you created an hidden field i each row, you can create a button once you close your table tag:

```
retour.append("<input type='button' value='Send' onclick='fun()'/>");
```

But you will have to put a condition to check if your query returned any rows. If it retured, use the above statement to append the button, else ignore it.